# spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size not working for Spring Framework 6.x and Oracle?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

A simple JPA application that fetches 100,000+ rows from a database is seeing a difference in performance using the spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size with Oracle for Spring Framework 5.x.

| Spring Boot Version | Java Version | Fetch Size | Time Elapsed (ms) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2.7.3 | 17 | 100000 | 24159 |
| 2.7.3 | 17 | 100 | 142283 |
| 3.0.3 | 17 | 100000 | 788145 |
| 3.0.3 | 17 | 100 | 525285 |

But with 6.x there is poor performance no matter the fetch size? Hibernate documentation makes no mention of this from what I can find. Thoughts?? Is there a hibernate setting that is missing for Spring Framework 6.x?

Expected result: Faster performance in database reads by increasing the fetch_size in Spring Framework 6.x

Comment: What are the queries that are executed old vs new? How many rows are you reading in both cases? What are the query plans that the database uses? There are so many questions open. It would be best you start out discussing this with your DBA and come back with a real question when you have one.

Comment: It seems it is a bug on hibernate : https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/jdbcfetchsize-seems-to-be-ignored/7626/7

Comment: Here's the bug report for the same: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16872

Answer (score 1):

Using @QueryHints(@QueryHint(name = HibernateHints.HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "500000")) on repository methods seems to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrade.

Upgrading also the Oracle driver to the latest version, solved the issue.

Comment: How exactly do I do that? I'm running the web app in  external tomcat 10.